# how to obtain predictive posteriors in pystan?

Tags: python, r, stan

I'm trying to move from using stan in R (I've mainly used the brms package) to pystan, but having trouble locating any methods in pystan that will give me predictive posterior distributions for new data. In R, I've been using `brms::posterior_linpred()` to do this. Does anyone know if this is possible in pystan?

If not, can it be bolted on without too much problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, they are not any Python libraries that do what the **brms** and **rstanarm** R packages do, i.e. come with precompiled Stan models that allow users to draw from the predictive distribution in the high-level language. There are things like prophet and survivalstan but those are for a pretty niche set of models.